# Flutter Error: no such module 'GoogleMaps'

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter

I am working in a project bought by a client. The project is Fluxstore. A E-commerce built with Flutter.

I can run the project in Android (emulator and device=). But iOS doesn't run. I get this following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           138,6s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/user./projects/project/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:3:8: error: no such module 'GoogleMaps'
import GoogleMaps
       ^
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

I looked up on solutions for this issue in Internet but nothing works. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Have you managed to find solution for this? If not, did you try to run flutter clean?

Comment: Did you got the solution for this issue? i'm also stuck here

Comment: Any solution for this issue. I am facing the same issue here

Answer (score 6):

```
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
pod update
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

delete all pod file. run `flutter clean`. then go to iOS folder and run `pod init`. It's create a pod file. Add  `pod 'GoogleMaps'` this line here before `target 'Runner' do`

I share my pod file code

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

end
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you check in the pubspec.yaml if the project still uses google_maps? Because if not, then you should remove the two lines in the `AppDelegate.swift`. (The import of google_maps and the `GMSServices.provideAPIKey`.

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because you opened the project in the wrong directory in xcode. If you open it correctly and try it, the problem will be solved.

Note: Applies to Flutter projects.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you import google map in your appdelgate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps //This line

    @UIApplicationMain
    @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
      override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
      ) -> Bool {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MAP API KEY")
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
      }
    }
```